# compare datetime.timedelta to datetime.now

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi, delta

I need to stop a script from a time set in a sql db. My idea is to use If else.

as you can see i'm not really good in python but keep going :-)

Below the script i'm using now.

I cant figure out how to compare the timedelta with a datetime now

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
import wiringpi as wiringpi
import os
import settings
from time import sleep
from time import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time 

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage: ./thermostat.py <scheduleid>"
        sys.exit()
scheduleid = sys.argv[1]

# Enable GPIO
os.environ['WIRINGPI_GPIOMEM'] = '1'
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()

# open a database connection
con = mdb.connect(host=settings.SQLSERVER,user=settings.SQLUSER,passwd=settings.SQLPASS,db=settings.SQLDB);

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor_actual = con.cursor ()
cursor_target = con.cursor ()
cursor_stats = con.cursor ()
cursor_endtime = con.cursor ()

# execute the SQL query using execute() method.
cursor_actual.execute ("SELECT temperature FROM temperature WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM temperature)")
cursor_target.execute (("SELECT targettemp FROM rules WHERE id = %s"),(scheduleid))
cursor_endtime.execute ("SELECT timeend FROM schedules WHERE id = '4'")


# fetch all of the rows from the query
actual = cursor_actual.fetchall()
target = cursor_target.fetchall()
endtime = cursor_endtime.fetchall()

# print the rows
for row in actual:
 actual = row[0]

for row in target:
 target = row[0]

#delta now time
utcnow = datetime.utcnow()
midnight_utc = datetime.combine(utcnow.date(), time(0))
delta = utcnow - midnight_utc

# Switching ON and OFF the boiler
if actual < target and endtime < delta.total_seconds():
    cursor_stats.execute("INSERT INTO stats(timestamp,currenttemp,targettemp,state) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,%s,%s,'ON')",(actual,target))
    print "The temperature is {} and the target temperature is {} so the heating is turned ON".format(actual,target)
    print endtime
    print delta.total_seconds()
    exec settings.on

else:
    cursor_stats.execute("INSERT INTO stats(timestamp,currenttemp,targettemp,state) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,%s,%s,'OFF')",(actual,target))
    print "The temperature is {} and the target temperature is {} so the heating is turned OFF".format(actual,target)
    print endtime
    print delta.total_seconds()
    exec settings.off

# close mysql cleanly
con.commit()
cursor_actual.close ()
cursor_target.close ()
con.close ()

# Exit the script
sys.exit()
```

the result of the script is as below

```
pi@Relay-Boiler:~/scripts $ ./3.py 1
The temperature is 21.05 and the target temperature is 40.0 so the heating is turned OFF
((datetime.timedelta(0, 68400),),)
77363.030178
```

thank you

Comment: How is the `timeend` inserted into the `schedules` table? It looks like your code is okay, but the dates you read from the schedule table are strange.

Comment: i m using phpmyadmin. i created the table and set the type as time. then i just put this 17:00:00

Comment: `61200 == 17 * 3600`, so it _sort of_ makes sense. What type is the `timeend` field in the database? If it's integer (and not date), maybe what phpmyadmin does is a sensible thing.

Comment: ha ok! where is the 3600 coming from? the timeend field type is time. thanks

Comment: 3600 seconds in an hour, apparently. Time deltas are measured in seconds internally.

Comment: doh! thanks for the clarification